# Block Texture missing only when placed

Tags: java, json, minecraft, minecraft-forge

Edit 2: I would like to rephrase this question as "Why isn't my texture loading? Is it because I've written my .json files poorly? Should I be registering my blocks/items differently?" Speaking of registering, I realise I haven't added my main mod file so here:

```
    package kijilas.mushroomMod;

    @Mod("mushroomforest")
    public class MushroomMod {
        public static MushroomMod instance;
        public static final String modid = "mushroomforest";
        private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(modid);   

        public MushroomMod() {
            instance = this;
    
            FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus().addListener(this::setup);
            FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus().addListener(this::clientRegistries);
    
            MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);
        }

        private void setup(final FMLCommonSetupEvent event) {
            logger.info("Setup method registered");
        }

        private void clientRegistries(final FMLClientSetupEvent event) {
            logger.info("Client registries method registered");
        }

        @Mod.EventBusSubscriber(bus = Mod.EventBusSubscriber.Bus.MOD)
        public static class RegistryEvents {
    
            @SubscribeEvent
            public static void registeritems(final RegistryEvent.Register<Item> event) {
                event.getRegistry().registerAll(
                        ItemList.fomes_sword = new Item(new Item.Properties().tab(ItemGroup.TAB_COMBAT)).setRegistryName(location("fomes_sword")),
                        ItemList.fomes_block = new BlockItem(BlockList.fomes_block, new Item.Properties().tab(ItemGroup.TAB_BUILDING_BLOCKS)).setRegistryName(BlockList.fomes_block.getRegistryName())
                );
        
                logger.info("Items registered.");           
            }
    
            @SubscribeEvent
            public static void registerblocks(final RegistryEvent.Register<Block> event) {
                event.getRegistry().registerAll(
                        BlockList.fomes_block = new Block(Block.Properties.of(Material.STONE).strength(0.75f).harvestTool(ToolType.AXE).sound(SoundType.WART_BLOCK)).setRegistryName(location("fomes_block"))
                );
        
                logger.info("Blocks registered.");          
            }
    
            private static ResourceLocation location(String name) {
                return new ResourceLocation(modid, name);
            }
        }
    }
```

(I've removed the imports for readability, but I've got no complaints from Eclipse about missing ones, and I have them all imported right after the "package kijilas.mushroomMod" line)

I have been trying to learn to create mods for minecraft.
Following tutorials by "Harry Talks":
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hlo-tBIhr0k&list=PLiDUvCGH5WEUcxyUKxHpQpDuinaiNp3it&index=7

I've a block, its item, and a sword (that doesn't yet act like a sword but that's fine).

I can take the block out of the creative inventory fine, and it has the right name, texture, etc.
But when I place the block down, it has the black and purple "missing texture" texture.

Here's my blockstate

```
    {
        "variants": {
            "": "mushroomforest:block/fomes_block"
        }
    }
```

Here's my model

```
    {
        "parent":"block/block",
        "textures": {
            "side":"mushroomforest:block/fomes_side",
            "top":"mushroomforest:block/fomes_top",
            "side_one":"mushroomforest:block/fomes_top"
        },
        "elements": [
            {
                "from": [0, 0, 0],
                "to": [16, 16, 16],
                "faces": {
                    "down": {"uv": [0, 0, 16, 16], "texture":"#top", "cullface":"down"},
                    "up": {"uv": [0, 0, 16, 16], "texture":"#top", "cullface":"up"},
                    "north": {"uv": [0, 0, 16, 16], "texture":"#side_one", "cullface":"north"},
                    "east": {"uv": [0, 0, 16, 16], "texture":"#side", "cullface":"east"},
                    "south": {"uv": [0, 0, 16, 16], "texture":"#side", "cullface":"south"},
                    "west": {"uv": [0, 0, 16, 16], "texture":"#side", "cullface":"west"}
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I don't have a block class because I'm just using the AbstractBlock class.
I have 3 texture.png files (each named appropriately).

The errors I'm getting (haven't been able to find any other errors) are

```
    [16Apr2021 17:53:35.199] [Worker-Main-12/WARN] [net.minecraft.client.renderer.model.ModelBakery/]: Exception loading blockstate definition: 'mushroomforest:blockstates/fomes_block.json' missing model for variant: 'mushroomforest:fomes_block#'
```

and

```
    [16Apr2021 17:53:35.200] [Worker-Main-12/WARN] [net.minecraft.client.renderer.model.ModelBakery/]: Exception loading blockstate definition: 'mushroomforest:blockstates/fomes_block.json' in resourcepack: 'Mod Resources': java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: "mushroomforest:block/fomes_block"
```

Here's the latest debug.log file:
https://pastebin.com/EK3xy4vL

I don't understand what I've done wrong, if anyone could help me would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: fomes_block item model:
{"parent":"mushroomforest:block/fomes_block"}

Answer (score 0):

I feel so stupid, my fomes_block.json model file was written

```
{
    "variants":{
        "": "mushroomforest:block/fomes_block"
    }
}
```

when is should have been

```
{
    "variants":{
        "": {"model":"mushroomforest:block/fomes_block"}
    }
}
```